# C# Solution into SVN projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, tfs

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I've been unable to find the information I'm looking for.

I'm working on a large C# solution, which contains a number of components shared with another 2 solutions.
My aim is to check the whole thing into an SVN server, but I'm uncertain the best way to go about this.

When I worked in a Java dev team, we used an SVN server and Maven to handle builds, so our projects were entirely modular.
Each project was checked into SVN as a separate entity, and Maven handled the retrieval of compiled artifacts, and all was well.

I would like to replicate this sort of strategy in C# using VS 2013, but I'm uncertain how to go about this other than checking in each project of the solution into its own SVN project.

This is not an issue as such, but we have 2 other solutions which use projects contained in our main solution.

If I were to check in the entire solution (as I would wish to so the solution files themselves are version controlled), the SVN checkout/checkin could become rather complex and unwieldy.
If I check in individual project from within the solution directory, I will need to come up with an svnignore policy that will stop the projects contained within the solution directory from being checked in to SVN again.

The SVN in this case will not be used for team development, but for handling merges and storing finalised tags, so will be running locally on my machine.

I'm pondering TFS as an alternative, but have no experience with it, so I'm unsure if it can be used in this way.

Can anybody advise if my proposed approach is actually possible for VS projects using SVN, or whether TFS would be a better option?

I would be happy to use an entirely different solution for source control, however I'm less inclined toward using GIT. For the uses we're intending, a more traditional client/server approach would suit out needs better, and the relearning time required for GIT just can't be spared at the moment.

If there are other posts/guides/existing advace on this subject that somebody can point me to, I would be grateful.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by TFS. Need to check in the entire solution(all in source control) and use local workspace, get the files mapping in local. For VS, all your source code are locally, just like in the local development environment. All your need is editing your code, checking in server, resolving the conflict, getting latest version.You even don't need to manually check out your solution(For local workspace in TFS, will automatically check out files).

Tree view of your project as below.

```
 -Your project
    -solution1
    -solution2
    -Main solution
    -common folder(which put the shared components)
```

You just need to add the common folder associated with the three solutions. Every change in the common folder will also defect with the three other solutions when checked in.